# Layout out elements within a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm having a very difficult time figuring out how to lay out this element. Here's what I want to do (apologies for my MS Paint skills):

[image: Layout]

Here, the gray box is supposed to be an ImageView. The red lines here are just to make the sections more clear - not worried abot how to draw them. The features that I'm trying to get are:

1. The ImageView is aligned relative to the topmost red line, and to the left edge of the green box.
2. The "TEXT" is to the right of the image, and centered vertically in its section.

Without the ImageView, this is pretty straightforward - just a LinearLayout with three TextViews and some padding. I've tried doing this wit a RelativeLayout, but I'm unsure of how to center Text within the box without relying on guessing at the padding/margin.

I figured out how to get the box hanging over. I created my RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#3AF">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#AAA">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But what I can't figure out is how to align the topmost TextView to the right of the ImageView. (Note - this is just my attempt. The layout type/style is entirely flexible at this point).

Here's a screenshot of how it looks in the designer:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: If the image is a fixed sized (in DP) then you can know how far to push the Text over.

Comment: You can use a `FrameLayout` to stack items and/or layouts on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_toRightOf
```

Should work... If not, can you explain what's wrong and what are your issues, because it works fine here...

Comment: As I have it, the `TextView` is inside of the `LinearLayout`, so I can't put it `toRightOf` the `ImageView`. Now, one thing that I did consider was laying this all out relatively, which I can make work by using extra `View`s for my background, but then I run into the problem of aligning the top `TextView` in the vertical middle of its container.

Comment: So put the LinearLayout on the right... but maybe you don't want all your textviews to be on the right and maybe only the first one? So divide your linearlayout in two parts. It's really hard for me to uderstand what you want and what's the problem...

Comment: Take a look at the green picture above - that's the layout that I'm going for. If you think of the red as dividing the green box into three sections - top, middle, bottom - what I want is the three to form what's conceptually a vertical LinearLayout. However, I want the gray box - the ImageView - to hang over the top edge of the green box, and I want the top TextView ("TEXT") to be to the right of the image, and centered vertically within the top green box. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your first line into your LinearLayout and then everything else in your RelativeLayout. I haven't tried this code, but if I understand your scenario correctly, it should do the trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#3AF">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#AAA">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
     <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```